# How to insert a particular value against one column of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am having a Table in SQL named: **Employee_Shift_Details** with the following columns:

```
[Shift_Id],[Emp_Name],[Group_Name],[Emp_Id],[Time],[Date],[DayOfWeek] 
//where **Shift_Id** is primary key.
```

Now I have a Gridview with some data in it. The gridView looks like this:

```
DayOfWeek        Date        8:45AM-6PM             2PM-11PM
Wednesday       1-Mar          John                  Olivia
Thursday        2-Mar          John                  Olivia
Friday          3-Mar          John                  Olivia
Saturday        4-Mar          Davis                 Clark          
Sunday          5-Mar          Davis                 Clark
```

Here all the employees are of Group A.

I want to insert this data into **Employee_Shift_Details** table but

- the Time column should have `8:45AM-6PM` for John and Davis as they are working in 8:45AM-6PM shift
- and `2PM-11PM` for Olivia and Clark (as shown in gridview).

**Can anyone help me how can I achieve this? 
Also before inserting it should check if the record already exists then not to insert.**

**PS**: Emp_Id can be left blank for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add table with name `tblshifts` and define start and end of each shift then in `Employee_Shift_Details` use `shiftID` also `recomnded` to use `employeeID` not name

Comment: I want to insert this as it is. I can't define start and end. So need code for the above logic only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop through the gridview by selecting the values in column 3 as `Emp_Name` and `column[3].Name` as `Time` (you need some casting here). Same thing goes for column 4 (2PM-11PM).

More generaly you can do 2 loops 1 for the gridrows and the other for the columns having different `Time` values.

**EDIT**

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gv.rows) {
    //
    var newRow = ds.Tables("Employee_Shift_Details").NewRow;

    //All the values below need to be casted properly
    newRow("DayOfWeek") = gvRow.cells[1].text;
    newRow("Date") = gvRow.cells[2].text;
    newRow("Emp_Name") = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
    newRow("Time") = gv.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text;

    //Save the newRow to the database
}
```

Same for `2PM-11PM` replacing 3 with 4 or even adding another loop layer if you have more than 2 colums of Time shifts (if you expect so).

Comment: This won't work for me as I need to insert the data for a single day.

Comment: I don't get the part _for a single day_

Comment: If I use this loop two times then it will add two dates on a single day so in a single loop i want to add all the information.

Comment: Can you give an example on how you want the data to be in the database [use the data u gave earlier].